# Best way to get data in laravel related to array of object ids with mongodb database

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, eloquent, database

I have a table user data is as follow:

```
_id:ObjectId("mongodbid"),
name:"acdfgf",
skills:[ObjectId("skills id"),ObjectId("skill id 2")],
created_at:date,
updated_at:date
```

Now I have to get the user data with skills data based on there id in one hit.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You mean you want to list all users who have the skills [1,2] for example?

Comment: No ,I want user data but with array of skills also with full detail of skills as we do in mysql join.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Consider `User` is your model name

[you should have set this model to access the mongoDb if you are using hybrid with mySql or MariaDB]

```
User::whereRaw(['skills' => '2'])->get();
```

let me know if this didn't work.

Comment: worked for fetching data based on query but how i have to apply join...

Comment: You should use relation rather than join query.

Comment: where should i have realtion with php and mongo

Comment: not in php and mongo...Relation between table...You have to define them in models. For more Read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Bro i know Laravel very well .Please look into my answer what i was trying to get

Answer (score 0):

Please find answer

```
$m = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager();

    $command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        'aggregate' => 'mytestusers',
        'pipeline' => [
            ['$match' => ['name' => 'Pankaj Choudhary']],

            ['$unwind'=>'$skills'],
            ['$lookup' => array('from'=>'mytestskills','localField'=>'skills','foreignField'=>'_id','as'=>'sdfg')],
            ['$unwind'=>'$sdfg'],

            ['$group'=>array('_id'=>array('_id'=>'$_id','name'=>'$name','email'=>'$email'),'skills'=>array('$push'=>'$skills'),'sdfg'=>array('$push'=>'$sdfg'))],


        ],
        'cursor' => new \stdClass,
    ]);
    $cursor = $m->executeCommand('targetjob-plus', $command);
    $result = $cursor->toArray();
```

Comment: set your input table first.